# Invalid Cookie Header and then it ask's for Authorization

Tags: java, httpclient, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a page that requires Siteminder Authentication, So I am trying to pass my username and password in the code itself to access that page and keep on crawling all the links that are there in that page. This is my `Controller.java` code. And from this MyCrawler class is getting called.

```
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController("/data/crawl/root");

            controller.addSeed("http://ho.somehost.com/");

            controller.start(MyCrawler.class, 10);  
            controller.setPolitenessDelay(200);
            controller.setMaximumCrawlDepth(3);
    }
}
```

And this is my MyCrawler.java code. In this I am passing my credentials(username and password) for siteminder authentication. And just wanted to make sure that authentication should be done in this MyCrawler code or the above Controller code..??? And this crawler code is taken from here `(http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/)`

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

    Pattern filters = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g"
            + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4" + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf"
            + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

    public MyCrawler() {


    }

    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {

        System.out.println("RJ:- " +url);

        DefaultHttpClient client = null;

        try
        {
            // Set url
            //URI uri = new URI(url.toString());

            client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, null),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test"));

            // Set timeout
            //client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                InputStream responseIS = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseIS));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Resource not available");
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( client != null )
            {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
        }


        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
        if (filters.matcher(href).matches()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (href.startsWith("http://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void visit(Page page) {
        int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
        String text = page.getText();
        List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();
        int parentDocid = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();

        System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        System.out.println("Number of links: " + links.size());
        System.out.println("Docid of parent page: " + parentDocid);
        System.out.println("=============");
    }   
}
```

I am printing the url so that I can see what url's are getting printed. So by that way it prints two url one the actual url that requires authentication and then some siteminder url. And when I run this project I get error as following..

```
RJ:- http://ho.somehost.com/net/pa/ho.xhtml
 WARN [Crawler 1] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: SMCHALLENGE=; expires=Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:52:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.somehost.com". Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:52:54 GMT
 WARN [Crawler 1] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Co## Heading ##okie: SMIDENTITY=nzFSq2U3g/C3C6/jkj/Ocghyh/njK; expires=Sat, 13 Jul 2013 02:52:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.somehost.com". Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 13 Jul 2013 02:52:54 GMT
null
 INFO [Crawler 1] Number of pages fetched per second: 0
RJ:- https://lo.somehost.com/site/no/176/sm.exhtml
 WARN [Crawler 1] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: SMCHALLENGE=; expires=Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:52:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.somehost.com". Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:52:56 GMT
 WARN [Crawler 1] Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: SMIDENTITY=IqsIPo; expires=Sat, 13 Jul 2013 02:52:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.somehost.com". Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 13 Jul 2013 02:52:56 GMT
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated..And If I copy paste that login url into the browser, then it ask for username and password and If I type my username and password, then I get the actual screen.

Comment: Not an answer, since I do not have any means to reproduce this issue. You appear to be using HttpClient from the HttpComponents project at Apache. I would suggest going through the tutorial first, especially the part about authentication cookies; your current problem is related to incorrect cookie handling. Apparently, you haven't realized or are ignorant about how SiteMinder authentication works as well, so I would suggest reading up whatever documents you have to understand how it works under the hood. Why is this important? Because you've been asking questions around this for two weeks.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, thanks for replying.. The same code of HttpClient works fine in my different project as I figured out what was the problem. And If I am using this same code in this project, then I am getting that error back. So that's why I was confused what wrong I am doing this time..

Comment: Well, then what is different across the two projects? Maybe that would give you an answer. Please update the question with that info, if you already know of it.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, Only the url that I am trying to access is different this time. And the username and password is also the same..

Comment: Well, I would start by looking at why the expiry date of the cookie is in the past `Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:52:54 GMT`. You ought to compare the behavior of the servers, in each of your cases, starting with the cookies issued. Certainly you cannot rule out the problem with the server. If you need more help, I would suggest carrying out a chat session.

Comment: @VineetReynolds let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1438/discussion-between-raihan-jamal-and-vineet-reynolds)

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the salient contents of the chat discussion for posterity, in case anyone experiences the same issue.

The warning message displayed, indicated that HttpClient was unable to parse the `Set-Cookie` header issued by SiteMinder. Analysis of the network traffic using Wireshark revealed the following:

- No expires attribute was set for the cookie SMSESSION, which was issued by SiteMinder. This is not the cause of the problem; it is just a note that the HTTP response from the server responsible for the warning needs to be looked.
- The warnings were issued for the cookies `SMCHALLENGE` and `SMIDENTITY`. Therefore, the responses containing the `Set-Cookie` headers for these two cookies need to examined.
- The problem could be in:

  - the cookie values themselves, or
  - the format of the dates in the expires attribute of the cookies.
- [Bug no 923](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-923) of HttpClient was fixed in version 4.1.1 of HttpClient and might contain an resolution. The fix, is for supporting both 2 and 4 digit years and might be the cause of the issue.

If the above (use of 4 digit years in the cookie expires value) turns out to be an incorrect root cause, then one must specify the date format used to parse the cookie value. This can be done by specifying the list of allowed/accepted date formats by using HttpClient in the following manner:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
request.getParams().setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, Arrays.asList("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

instead of the existing calls:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The pattern specified `EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z` is a valid pattern for the dates that appear to be parsed incorrectly (going by the messages in the console). You will need to add additional patterns if there are other date formats that are not handled correctly by HttpClient. For details on the format used, see the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class documentation.