# Httpclient Cookie Handling on AppEngine (when using WebDriver)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, webdriver

I want to use [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) (from Selenium; using the most recent version 2.18.0) to login to Amazon Web Services, extract the current $ spent, and send it via e-mail. My plan is to run this on Google AppEngine, so I created a Google Web Application Project.

**Problem**: When I run the code as Plain-Java, instead of AppEngine Servlet, it works fine and I'm able to extract the data I need. But running the same code as a AppEngine application results in this warning and Amazon redirects me to the login page:

```
    28.01.2012 15:46:32 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
    WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: aws-at-main="..."; Version=1; Domain=.amazon.com; Max-Age=630720000; Expires=Fri, 23-Jan-2032 14:46:37 GMT; Path=/; Secure". Unable to parse expires attribute: Fri, 23-Jan-2032 14:46:37 GMT
```

**Analysis**:

- When calling `driver.manage().getCookies()` I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid port: -1` (full stacktrace at the end of the post). With plain Java I get the set of cookies.
- I tried different `BrowserVersions`, problem does not change.
- I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702914) with a similar looking problem, but I don't know how to access the underlying HTTPClient of WebDriver to set the date pattern. Maybe the version of `com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies` AppEngine uses is old and still has the bug mentioned there? The version delivered with WebDriver/Selenium is `httpclient-4.1.2.jar`.

**Question**: Does anyone know how what's the difference of the normal to the AppEngine httpclient and how this can be fixed?

**Possible Workarounds**: Does anyone know how I could set the date pattern mentioned in the afromentioned [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702914) in WebDriver?
 Or can I access the response header before the cookies are parsed to "fix" the expiry date accordingly?

**Java code snipped:**

```
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_6);
    driver.get("https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary");

    // Fill in mail
    WebElement mailElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email"));
    mailElement.sendKeys("qwerty");

    // Fill in password
    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password"));
    passwordElement.sendKeys("qwertz");

    // Submit form
    WebElement submitElement = driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit"));
    submitElement.submit();
```

**Full stack trace:**

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid port: -1
at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin.<init>(CookieOrigin.java:58)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.getCookies(CookieManager.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitOptions.getCookies(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1162)
at org.cloudcycle.awsconsumption.AWSConsumptionMonitorServlet.doGet(AWSConsumptionMonitorServlet.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```